# iOS: convert CGPoint in screen coordinates to CATransform3D in iCarousel?

Tags: ios, coordinate-systems, cgpoint, icarousel, coordinate-transformation

I wanted to add a possibility to drag elements inside the `carousel` and I have some troubles with positioning and transformations of a draggable element.

As I understand it is better to temporarily hide/delete the draggable element and create its proxy outside the carousel item array which represents the position and transform properties of the real one.

The problem is how to set the correct transform of such proxy item according to its position. One view from `items` array has its own index and carousel scroll offset (which is common for all the items). But the separated view has a position only (in better case it stores the transform of the original carousel item and I can find the nearest view/views).

So how to convert the given screen point to offset in iCarousel coordinate system? The transform matrices are enough complex: rotation, perspective and translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution but in my particular case it looks awful. I need to move along y only so on each drag position changed event:

```
CGFloat newY = currentTouchPosition.y - positionOnTouchStartDragging.y + (draggedPageIndex - carousel.scrollOffset) * spacing * carousel.bounds.size.height;
CGFloat delta = self.bounds.size.height * spacing;
CATransform3D result = [carousel transformForItemViewWithOffset:newY / deltaY];
```

where spacing is a variable given in carousel or via its delegate.